# Mysql query error unix timestamp

Tags: mysql

can anybody explain me how this Mysql query result is possible.

```
select 
sec_to_time(
unix_timestamp('2014-10-26 02:00:00')-
unix_timestamp('2014-10-25 20:00:00')
);
```

result:

```
07:00:00
```

should be:

```
06:00:00
```

Comment: daylight saving time? It is saturday and sunday...

Answer (score 2):

Use MySQL `TIMEDIFF` or `TIME_TO_SEC` like that :-

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2014-10-26 02:00:00', '2014-10-25 20:00:00'))
```

Comment: ok. i still can't understand why in this specific date (all sat. and sun.), mysql give me wrong result.

Comment: Apparently your server's time zone is not set or is set improperly and you're getting GMT rather than local time. More about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql